# Constant values can modify inside app controller?

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp-2.0

I define a a variable in bootstarp.php , In some cases I need to change that value from APP controller. Is it possible in cakephp

define('MAXVALUE',3);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no
due to the nature of constants

thats why Configure::read() and write() should be used for such settings.